# Strange characters/text when installing PHPBB3 forum

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpbb3

I am trying to install a PHPBB3 forum, and get strange characters/text after the install on certain pages - everything seems to install correctly though...no errors from the installer.. :(

Originally it only appeared on the "new topic" or "post a reply" pages, but now it is appearing in various different places!

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot 1]

[Screenshot 2 http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/9343/screenshot1fv.png](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/9343/screenshot1fv.png)

Comment: Thanks Andy, didn't realise you could embed images directly onto a post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its a problem with the custom/modified style you are using. Try changing the style back to the default styles or downloading an up-to-date style from [phpbb.com](http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/styles/board_styles-12/).

I'm sure as soon you change the style the text wont appear. (make sure to clear the cache in the Administration Control Panel when you have made the change)